# Problem with changing array indices with sympy and numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy

I have a program that is supposed to output the rotation matrix for a rotation of an arbitrary angle about an arbitrary axis. I start with a blank, 3x3 numpy array. I go through each element of the array using nested loops and set the value according to [this awesome method](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/rotation_12.pdf).

From sympy I use KroneckerDelta and LeviCivita, from numpy I use array.

In my code, I have included the troubleshooting methods I used. The program behaves exactly as I expect at each step except that it seems like it is just not adding the values to the components. Even more confusing, it works for theta=pi.

Can anyone spot my silly mistake?

```py
from numpy import array, ndarray, outer, dot, cross, array_equal, identity
from numpy import concatenate, zeros
from numpy import sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan, exp
from numpy.linalg import norm, inv
from numpy import pi, sqrt, arange
from sympy import KroneckerDelta, LeviCivita


def RotationMatrix(axis, angle):

    axis = axis / norm( axis )
    R = array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            R[i,j] += int(cos(angle)) * int(KroneckerDelta(i,j))
            R[i,j] += (1-cos(angle)) * axis[i] * axis[j]
            for k in range(0,3):
                #R[i,j] -= sin(angle) * axis[k] * LeviCivita(i,j,k)
                print(KroneckerDelta(i,j),LeviCivita(i,j,k),i,j,axis[i],axis[j],cos(angle),sin(angle))
            print(R)

    return R
```

Comment: Could you include the output of your code in your question? Why do you convert the cosine to an integer in the line with the `KroneckerDelta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which edit made the difference but I did the following:

-Use numpy.zeros instead of hand-making an array of zeros

-Use a dummy variable "Temp" to temporarily hold the values that are to
 be added to the rotation matrix

Here is the final code:

```
#-v- You input an axis of rotation and an angle of rotation
# this outputs the corresponding rotation matrix
def RotationMatrix(axis, angle):

Temp = 0
axis = Normalized( axis )
R = zeros((3,3))#array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        Temp += cos(angle) * KroneckerDelta(i,j)
        Temp += (1-cos(angle)) * axis[i] * axis[j] 
        R[i,j] = R[i,j] + Temp
        Temp = 0
        for k in range(0,3):
            Temp -= sin(angle) * axis[k] * LeviCivita(i,j,k)
            R[i,j] = R[i,j] + Temp
            Temp = 0

return R
#-^-
```